# Creating lables - using data from excel sheets - selecting specific column

Tags: labels, datatool, excel

I have to create desk slips (labels). For this data is available in excel sheet. The column names are - RollNo, Subject, Venue of Exam (examination center).

Presently we are creating desk slips using `CSVtools`. The label looks like -

```
NAME OF EXAMINATION

Subject : xyz

Roll No. : 000000
```

For this we have to create several csv data sheets - venue of exam wise and subject wise. Is there a way that without creating several csv data sheets we can create labels exam venue wise and subject wise?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{csvtools}
\usepackage[left=.5cm,right=.5cm,top=.5cm,bottom=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
RollNo,Subject,Venue
022701,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
022702,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
022704,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
022705,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
022706,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
022707,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
022708,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
022709,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
022709,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
022710,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
023001,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
023002,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
023004,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
023005,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
023006,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
023007,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
023008,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
023009,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
023010,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\applyCSVfile{data.csv}{% here put the name of the file
%\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent\fbox{\parbox{6.3cm}{%
{\color{white}.}\\[7pt]
\centering{\LARGE UGC NET - 2014}\\[2pt]
\raggedright
{\Large Subject : \insertSubject}\\[5pt]
{\Large Roll No. : \textbf{0\insertRollNo}}\\[12pt]
}} % This is for parbox
%\end{multicols}
}% This is for CSV file


\end{document}
```

Comment: IMHO your problem looks too wide for the audience. It would be better if you could please let us know what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi and welcome, the thing is that we are not knowing what you are doing or what a csv looks like. Right now, i am not even sure what a *desk slip* is. If you extend the question giving some explanations, i guess we can find a solution.

Comment: I have added the code you have sent tugindia mailing list to the question. Hope that is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that should serve as a starting point. This uses `datatool` package. I have added a column with a short key for `center` in addition to your columns.

```
center,RollNo,Subject,Venue
Bangalore,022701,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022702,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022704,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022705,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
```

In fourth column, you may specify the full center if you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=.5cm,right=.5cm,top=.5cm,bottom=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
center,RollNo,Subject,Venue
Bangalore,022701,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022702,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022704,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022705,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022706,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022707,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022708,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022709,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022709,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Bangalore,022710,Sociology,Deptt. of Physics
Mangalore,023001,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
Mangalore,023002,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
Mangalore,023004,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
Mangalore,023005,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
Mangalore,023006,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
Mangalore,023007,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
Mangalore,023008,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
Mangalore,023009,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
Mangalore,023010,Psychology,Deptt. of Physics
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}

\begin{document}
This is for Bangalore center

\DTLforeach*[\DTLisopenbetween{\center}{B}{C}]{data}{%
 \center=center,\roll=RollNo,\sub=Subject, \venue=Venue}{%
   \noindent\fbox{\parbox{6.3cm}{%
{\color{white}.}\\[7pt]
\centering{\LARGE UGC NET - 2014}\\[2pt]
\raggedright
{\Large Subject : \sub}\\[5pt]
{\Large Roll No. : \textbf{\roll}}\\[12pt]
}}\hfill % This is for parbox
}%

\clearpage
This is for Mangalore

\DTLforeach*[\DTLisopenbetween{\center}{M}{N}]{data}{%
 \center=center,\roll=RollNo,\sub=Subject, \venue=Venue}{%
   \noindent\fbox{\parbox{6.3cm}{%
{\color{white}.}\\[7pt]
\centering{\LARGE UGC NET - 2014}\\[2pt]
\raggedright
{\Large Subject : \sub}\\[5pt]
{\Large Roll No. : \textbf{\roll}}\\[12pt]
}}\hfill % This is for parbox
}%

\clearpage
This is for Sociology

\DTLforeach*[\DTLisopenbetween{\sub}{S}{T}]{data}{%
 \center=center,\roll=RollNo,\sub=Subject, \venue=Venue}{%
   \noindent\fbox{\parbox{6.3cm}{%
{\color{white}.}\\[7pt]
\centering{\LARGE UGC NET - 2014}\\[2pt]
\raggedright
{\Large Subject : \sub}\\[5pt]
{\Large Roll No. : \textbf{\roll}}\\[12pt]
}}\hfill % This is for parbox
}%

\clearpage
This is for  Psychology

\DTLforeach*[\DTLisopenbetween{\sub}{P}{Q}]{data}{%
 \center=center,\roll=RollNo,\sub=Subject, \venue=Venue}{%
   \noindent\fbox{\parbox{6.3cm}{%
{\color{white}.}\\[7pt]
\centering{\LARGE UGC NET - 2014}\\[2pt]
\raggedright
{\Large Subject : \sub}\\[5pt]
{\Large Roll No. : \textbf{\roll}}\\[12pt]
}}\hfill % This is for parbox
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that for large csv files, this may compile slowly. This can be cured to some extent by using `pgfplotstable`. Here a large, single data file can be filtered out for a particular center or subject and individual csv files can be created on the fly. Once these are created, you can create the labels using your `csvtools` package way or using `datatool`. Here is the sample code that uses the same `data.csv` as in the previous code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=.5cm,right=.5cm,top=.5cm,bottom=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable,xstring}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{datatool}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\data
\begin{document}
%%----------------------------------------------------------subjectwise
%% following will filter all Psychology rows and save it as Psychology.csv
\pgfplotstablesave[col sep=comma,
    row predicate/.code={%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{Subject}\of\data%
    \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{Psychology}{%True            %% >>imp<< Psychology is case sensitive, psychology won't work
    \relax}%
    {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%False
  }%
]
{\data}
{Psychology.csv}
%%----------------------------------------------------------
%% from here use datatool
\DTLloaddb{Psychology}{Psychology.csv}
\DTLforeach{Psychology}{%
 \center=center,\roll=RollNo,\sub=Subject, \venue=Venue}{%
   \noindent\fbox{\parbox{6.3cm}{%
{\color{white}.}\\[7pt]
\centering{\LARGE UGC NET - 2014}\\[2pt]
\raggedright
{\Large Subject : \sub}\\[5pt]
{\Large Roll No. : \textbf{\roll}}\\[12pt]
}}\hfill % This is for parbox
}%

\clearpage
%%---------------------------------------------------------- centerwise
%% following will filter all Bangalore rows and save it as bangalore.csv
\pgfplotstablesave[col sep=comma,
    row predicate/.code={%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{center}\of\data%
    \IfStrEq{\pgfplotsretval}{Bangalore}{%True                       %% >>imp<< Bangalore is case sensitive
    \relax}%
    {\pgfplotstableuserowfalse}%False
  }%
]
{\data}
{bangalore.csv}
%%----------------------------------------------------------
%% from here use datatool/csvtools
\DTLloaddb{bangalore}{bangalore.csv}
\DTLforeach{bangalore}{%
 \center=center,\roll=RollNo,\sub=Subject, \venue=Venue}{%
   \noindent\fbox{\parbox{6.3cm}{%
{\color{white}.}\\[7pt]
\centering{\LARGE UGC NET - 2014}\\[2pt]
\raggedright
{\Large Subject : \sub}\\[5pt]
{\Large Roll No. : \textbf{\roll}}\\[12pt]
}}\hfill % This is for parbox
}%
\end{document}
```